# Why in C without a semicolon gives an error?

Tags: c

Why does it throw an error in the seventh round without semicolons (;). When do you need to put such semicolons in the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define S 10

void print_arr(int *arr, int size) {
    int *p = arr + S;
    for(;arr < p; arr++) {
        printf("%d ", *arr);
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[S] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    print_arr(arr, S);
    return 0;
}
```

if you try without a semicolon (;) then it gives the following error

```
main.c:7:23: error: expected ';' before ')' token
    7 |     for(arr < p; arr++) {
      |                       ^
      |                       ;
```

Comment: a `for` loop has 3 statements or expressions as part of its configuration

Comment: @Kuttubek Is it so difficult to read the description of the for loop in a book for beginners on C?!

Comment: @DanielA.White The for loop does not have statements.

Comment: The compiler has no idea whether you omitted the first part or the third part, if that gives you an idea why the syntax is needed. You omitted the first, and the compiler guessed incorrectly it was the last.

Comment: Why does your spellchecker complain when you write "I dont care"?  Because an apostrophe is required in the word "don't".  It's not optional.  Similarly, in a `for` loop in C, although the three expressions are all optional, the two separating semicolons are required.  You have to type them, the parser is expecting them.

Comment: Programming is all about rules.  Some rules are arbitrary, some of them make sense.  Some rules you absolutely have to follow, some you can decide to break if you know what you're doing.  Some rules are more like guidelines, and it's a matter of opinion how often to follow them.  Some rules can be gotten around if you do lots of work to redesign things.  But for the absolute rules, unless you're willing to redesign things, you just have to accept them, and move on.  (In this case, though, as Weather Vane's comment explains, the rule requiring both semicolons is *not* arbitrary.)

Comment: Semicolon is used to terminate one or more statements in blocks between `{` `}`. But despite the appearance their use in `for()` loops is unrelated. The for-loop requires 2 semicolons. though each of the parts can be empty.  There are a number of places where C uses punctuation in completely different ways. Asterisk `*` means multiplication or pointer de-reference and comma `,` delimits function arguments and can be used to chain statements. Programming languages have greater need for punctuation than natural languages for which character sets and keyboards were designed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `for` loop consists of four parts:

`for(init;condition;iteration) { body }`

For the compiler to know what is used as `init`, `condition` or `iteration`, you separate it via semicolon. if you want to keep one of the parts empty, you simply write a semicolon.

`for(;i < 10;i++)` is a loop that has no initialisation. only a condition and an iteration statement.

`for(int i= 0;; i++)` has no condition and

`for(int i=0;i < 10;)` has no iteration statement.

writing  `for(i < 10; i++)` is simply not valid syntax.

Comment: And `for(; i < 10; )` is a `while` loop in disguise, and `for(;;)` is an infinite loop.

Comment: a for loop in it's entirety is just a while loop.

Comment: Not really, @Raildex — the behaviour of `continue` in a `while` loop is different from its behaviour in a `for` loop.